# Pass stdin as argument in sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, command, stdin

I have to write a command were we have to find files, calculate an md5 code and then put that into a textfile. Finding the files isn't hard, just

```
find -type f
```

Now I have a list of files and for each file i have to find the md5 code. I know the code to generate an md5 code

```
openssl dgst -md5 <file>
```

But how do I use piping (no scripting) to have something like this`

```
filename md5code
```

I already tried

```
while read line do... done
```

but that didn't work. I thaught i had to use sed, but i don't really now how. My closest try (I think) was this:

```
find dir -type f | sed "s/^\(.*\)$/\1 $( openssl dgst -md5 \1 )/" >> file.txt
```

But it doesn't recognise \1...

I tried it with the -exec option in find like this:

```
md5$ find dir -type f -exec sed "s/^\(.*\)$/\1 $( openssl dgst -md5 {} )/" \;
```

But it doesn't recognise the {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command substitution won't work within single quotes but also, I would suggest using the `-exec` switch rather than a pipe. You can also use `-print` (or `-printf` if your version of find supports it), although the filename is included in the output of the openssl command on my system anyway so maybe you don't need it. Try this:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f ' -exec openssl dgst -md5 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xargs` command to process the list of files returned by the `find` command.

```
find dir -type f | xargs md5sum >> file.txt
```

Most Unix-like operating systems should have the `md5sum` utility installed so I’ve used this instead of `openssl dgst -md`.
The `xargs` command takes a list of files as input and then builds a command by using these as arguments to the `md5sum` command.

If you have filenames with spaces or other unusual characters, you’ll need to use:

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum >> file.txt
```

The `-print0` option uses the NULL character to separate the list of files returned by the `find` command and the `-0, --null` option for `xargs` tells it to use the NULL instead of whitespace to delimit the input items.

Note: this will work with the GNU versions of these tools. I don’t know about other versions as it’s not adopted by the [POSIX specification for find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).